# How to access protected method from another package in mockito?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
//this is src/a/b
package a.b;

class C 
{
     protected Api getApi();
}
```

and test like this:

```
//and this is test/a/d
package a.d;

class TestE {
     @Test
     public void test()
     {
          C mockedC = spy(new C());
          doReturn(*somemockedapi*).when(mockedC).getApi(); // this one doesn't work!
          .....
     } 
}
```

It will work if class in tests is in tests/a/b, but this is not a solution because we need access to some stuff from src/a/d. And obviously this function is accessible via inheritance, so is there any way to let mockito mock it in such case?

Comment: You'll have to use PowerMock to do that.

Comment: PowerMock in not what I want, question is about mockito itself

Answer (score 2):

This is potentially quite dangerous, but can be done.

```
//reflectively get the method in question
Method myMethod = mockedC.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getApi");

//manually tell java that the method is accessible
myMethod.setAccessible(true);

//call the method
myMethod.invoke(myClass, null);

//PLEASE SET THE FIELD BACK TO BE UNACCESSIBLE
myMethod.setAccessible(false);
```